# Getting images from Amazon S3 in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm developing a website with AngularJS in frontend that sends requests to a Rails 4 API backend. I have to manage quite images, so I would like to use Amazon S3 (but I'm a newbie with this and I'm a bit lost).

I have uploaded an image to the folder in a new bucket (yanpy.dev) I have created in the path:

```
img/boats/1/1.jpg
```

How can I get this image to display it in a view in my AngularJS front-end?

Im trying something like:

```
<img src="http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/img/boats/1/1.jpg">
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Could you check if this works 
<img ng-src="http://yanpy.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/img/boats/1/1.jpg">

Comment: Configure S3 to allow access. If it is for a public website you might want to enable public access in S3.

Comment: @Sebastian I made the image public in S3 and it works. However, from the security point of view, is this right? Should it be public?

Comment: if you have a website which should be publicly accessible you must make it public (read-only of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Sebastian comment above. Point for him.